# breezeJS why create a new entityManagerProvider for each unit of work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, repository, breeze, unit-of-work

I am new to BreezeJS but very interested. I would like to incorporate it into an Angular/Node project that I currently have underway.

I have been reading through documentation and looking at the samples. One sample that I have been reviewing is the TempHire sample that can be found here:
https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/blob/master/node/tempHire

I can't understand why they create a new entityManagerProvider for every UnitOfWork. It seems like a lot of wasted effort. I am sure there is a reason for it and I am just not getting it because of my lack of knowledge of breeze or the unit of work pattern.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is in the documentation: "UOWs can be shared between ViewModels if different parts of the UI work with the same data, but each UOW remains a unique sandbox."

In angularjs, factories-services are singletons so when you create a UOW service you have an entityManager created for it too.

Inside that UOW you put all the data-repositories you want to work with and use it for your business code.

Every time you want to work with those data you just inject the "unitofwork" service you created and no extra entityManager will be created. "UnitOfWork" service-factory has a "get" method.

But in the case you want to use a new clean instance of the UnitOfWork service with an empty entityManager cache then you just call unitOfWork.create() that will make a new enityManager.

An example of a business scenario like this is explained here :http://breeze.github.io/doc-cool-breezes/multiple-entitymanagers.html